# Unittest of AngularJS Controller with Jasmine and Karma "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unit-test an angularjs controller and get this error message when running Karma:

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?
Sorry, it's my first time testing something.

Controller:

```
angular
    .module('my')
    .controller('MyCtrl', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'myFactory'];

function MyController($scope,myFactory) {

    $scope.thingy = {};

//[..]
    function getThingys() {
        myFactory.getThingys(function () {}).then(function (data) {
            //SUCCESS
            $scope.thingy = data;
        });
    } 
}
```

Test:

```
var scope;
var controller;
var mockedMyFactory;

beforeEach(module('my'));

beforeEach(module('my', function ($provide) {
    mockedMyFactory = {
        getThingys: jasmine.createSpy()
    };
    $provide.value('myFactory', mockedMyFactory);
}));

beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, myFactory) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
        $scope: scope, myFactory
    });
}));

describe('this', function () {
    it('is a dummy spec', function () {
        expect(2 + 2).toEqual(4);
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see where you mocking the myFactory.getThingys

Comment: I thought I was doing this here?
beforeEach(module('my', function ($provide) {
    mockedMyFactory = {
        getThingys: jasmine.createSpy() <-
    };
    $provide.value('myFactory', mockedMyFactory);
}));

Answer (score 0):

To mock the service:

```
 var $httpBackend;
 var myFactory; 

 beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {    
        // Set up the mock http service responses
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

        // backend definition common for all tests
        myFactory= $injector.get('myFactory');

        $httpBackend.when('GET', 'url for call').respond({mock data});
}

 afterEach(function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });
```

Comment: Now i get 
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"
for the line 
"mock data".
And why do I have to use angular.mock.inject and not just angular.inject?

Comment: You have to replace the "mock data" with a sample data (ex: {'property1': "value1", .... }. You don't have to user angular.mock.inject.